# Training weak learners in using video or image dataset on TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Hi I have a problem statement where I have to train an **action recognizer** using videos.
but due to non availability of good dataset there is a slight misclassification.
Is there any setting or function where I can train the misclassified or **weak learners** by assigning them more weights.
Its sounds similar like Xgboost but I want something which can work on **Deep Learning** frame works and on Image and Video data set

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In this site, you can compare many models and get dataset
https://paperswithcode.com/task/pose-estimation